# New Microsoft Graph API - App-only access

Tags: office365, office365-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

I want to check the calendars from several users. Therefore, I need app-only access (because the app needs more rights than the logged in user).

With the "old" API this was possible by following these instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365

With the new Microsoft Graph API this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to make this work? I want to use the Microsoft Graph API for all the Office 365 API functions which I need in the app.

Thanks in advance!

(Edit: Including error message.)

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. Trace ID: 718db531-d789-4b45-ae9d-c2e53f3786fd Correlation ID: 6a157ae5-7dc3-4470-81c0-f410e14f9c04 Timestamp: 2015-11-27 12:40:33Z ---> System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert. bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

I gave full delegated and full application persmissions. Here is the token which I get:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","scope":"Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.Read Contacts.ReadWrite Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Directory.Write Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected full_access_as_user Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp offline_access openid People.Read People.ReadWrite Sites.Read.All Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All user_impersonation","expires_on":"1448974661","not_before":"1448970761","resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com/","pwd_exp":"582983","pwd_url":"https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ChangePassword.aspx","access_token":"eyJ---------zQXg","refresh_token":"AAABAA--------pYSAA","id_token":"eyJ0eXAi-------4wIn0."}
```

I don't have the rights to read other calendar than my.

Edit:
I can't get the App-Token...heres my code (App-Token worked before when I was not using the new graph api)

```
        string authority = appConfig["AuthorizationUri"].Replace("common", appConfig["ida:TenantId"]);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        string certfile = appConfig["o365_CertPath"];

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certfile, // password for the cert file containing private key 
                                                    appConfig["o365_CertPassword"],
                                                    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(appConfig["ida:ClientId"], cert);

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", cac);
        this.currentAccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

I tried different endpoints by AcquireTokenAsync. 
I always get the errormessage:

**{"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature.\r\nTrace ID: 6fe2a6bd-77d3-47a8-83d4-e10aea69b88a\r\nCorrelation ID: 53071578-1c16-4c17-8f77-fc5821c18d4b\r\nTimestamp: 2015-12-02 08:05:25Z"}**

Thanks again

Comment: Which part of those instructions don't work? What error message are you getting, or what options are you missing?

Comment: Hi, I get the following response when I try to use the API with the App Only token: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature.
Trace ID: 718db531-d789-4b45-ae9d-c2e53f3786fd
Correlation ID: 6a157ae5-7dc3-4470-81c0-f410e14f9c04
Timestamp: 2015-11-27 12:40:33Z ---> System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: And you're sure you set the public certificate in the app manifest matching the private key used to sign the client assertion?

Comment: I'm sure yes. Because it worked before...Is the problem maybe the fact that I'm using the clientlibraries? ....Theres another interessting issue. I've granted ALL permissions for the users (to read any calendar in the directory) but by executing this REST command "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/events" I get the 403 error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AJRames Sorry - little confused now.  The previous message suggested that you had trouble acquiring an app-only access token for Microsoft Graph (please make sure to set https://graph.microsoft.com/ as the resource).  Now you appear to be getting a 403 calling the API - so do you have an access token now?  Also, are you sure in the Azure Management Portal, that you selected the Application permissions (and not the delegated permissions).  Any you could decode your access token using jwt.calebb.net and update your question with the decoded access token claims please?

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusing. I gave full application and full delegated permission, but with delegated it wont work either... Anyway I have an token, but it seems that I dont have rights or doing something wrong. I will update my Post with the claims on monday. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added the token...

Comment: @AJRames Wow - yes.  Looks like you've selected every permission!  Anyways - here is your problem I believe.  The token above is a delegated (app+user) token.  I'm guessing that your request is to read ANOTHER user's events?  The delegated token + existing APIs allow the caller to ONLY read their own data (their own messages, events and contacts).  We will be adding the capability to read other user's Outlook data using a delegated token, but we don't have it yet.  The only way to do this right now, is to use an app-only token. Can you try that again and post your app-only token please?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT thanks for the explanation! I analyzed the method to get the App Only token. At my edited post you can see that I'm not able to get this token. Requiring the Access Token causes an error. Thanks again!

Comment: Now I have a token, but by executing this line of code I get the "Error occurred while processing this request" - var value = await client.Users.GetById(user.email).Events.ExecuteAsync();

Comment: Ok. The problem is caused due the CSOM... Using the token by executing this command works: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('xxx@xxx')/events. Unfortunately I already used the client libraries in the code....I don't want to write new methods and class additionally to the libraries...

Comment: Trying to understand this response.  So you have an existing application that already makes use of various client libraries (.Net?) to call SharePoint and Outlook?  Or are you extending your app to include calls to Outlook, and for this were looking at the Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was using Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1 from the PnP site. I switched to using Makecert and everything worked. Basically followed Richards exact instructions here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/05/03/performing-app-only-operations-on-sharepoint-online-through-azure-ad.aspx